# Windows PC as server (for Mac users)

Tags: windows, osx, remote-desktop, server

We are setting up a Windows PC to be accessible to all the users in the office. The users will be using Mac computers.

This machine will be a workstation capable of some really complicated computer graphics (Autocad, 3ds Max, Maya and so on).

What type of software would be the most usable for this type of use case? Would a normal remote desktop software do the trick or should I designate this computer as a server and have users share bits and pieces of it?

Comment: What do you mean by "be accessible to all users"? Spell out your *specific* needs.

Comment: simple, a user wants to use Autocad from his mac. he connects to the windows machine and uses it and does whatever he needs to do with the file.

Comment: You mean screen-sharing to drive the Windows PC remotely from the Mac? If so, what performance requirements do you need (just occasional tweaks in Autocad, or hours of regular work)? Or do you mean simply file-sharing? Post your clarifications as edits to the Question rather than as comments. Make your Question more specific and detailed. As it is now, much too vague to get a good answer.

Comment: Microsoft Remote Desktop will allow one user at a time to access the Windows machine - not really a good use of resources; it would be better to specify them better [or in the case of 3DS Max which isn't available for Mac, more appropriate] desktop machines & let them work at full speed locally.  The software you are specifying is really not suited to remote working.